# How to hookup Humanizer for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, humanizer

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and I'm trying to hook up the [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) framework into the Razor Pages view pipeline using `IDisplayMetadataProvider`. I'd like for all of my views to transform my model properties to "title case" strings on my labels.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```cs
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

With the class definition above, I'd like for my labels to automatically use the Humanizer `To.TitleCase`  for anytime I say `@Html.DisplayNameFor(...)`:

```html
<div>
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>

<div>
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName): @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName)
</div>
```

I'd expect to see:

```
   First Name: Joe
   Last Name: Smith
```

## Solution (UPDATED)

I was able to configure this in classic ASP.NET MVC using the tutorial at the bottom of the Humanizer Readme page ([explained here](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#mix-this-into-your-framework-to-simplify-your-life)). After looking around the web for a while, I did find [this post](https://www.michael-whelan.net/using-humanizer-with-asp-dotnet-core/) from Michael Whelan:

```cs
public class HumanizerMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        var propertyAttributes = context.Attributes;
        var modelMetadata = context.DisplayMetadata;
        var propertyName = context.Key.Name;

        if (IsTransformRequired(propertyName, modelMetadata, propertyAttributes))
            modelMetadata.DisplayName = () => propertyName.Humanize().Transform(To.TitleCase);
    }

    private static bool IsTransformRequired(string propertyName, DisplayMetadata modelMetaData, IReadOnlyList<object> propertyAttributes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelMetaData.SimpleDisplayProperty))
            return false;

        if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        if (propertyAttributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any())
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

It took a little different approach with an interface, rather than inheriting from a class. This was the trick to hook into the pipeline for ASP.NET Core *Razor Pages*. Here was the code needed in the **Startup.cs** `ConfigureServices(...)` handler:

```cs
services
   .AddRazorPages()
   .AddMvcOptions(m => m.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new HumanizerMetadataProvider()));
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

### FOUND IT

This was a [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK) issue. ‍♂️

The fix was here:

```cs
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelMetaData.SimpleDisplayProperty))
      return false;
```

Once the if statement was fixed, the "First Attempt" worked as expected.